# Prevent react router reloading API call when pressing back button. Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-router

There are two pages - the main one with a list of elements and a page with a detailed description of the element. Used react-router.

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={PokemonCardContainer} />
    <Route path="/pokemon/:pokemonName" component={Pokemon} />
</Switch>
```

On the main page with the list, a request api is generated, which returns 20 elements. Further, when we reach the end of the list, the api request is updated - another 20 items are loaded, etc.[image]

The detailed description page is implemented by the button "I Choose You!"

```
<Link to={`pokemon/${pokemonName}`}>
   {pokemonName}, I Choose You!
</Link>
```

On the detailed description page there is a button "Return to Home"

```
const handleGoToHomePage = () => {
    props.history.push({
    pathname: "/",
   });
 };
```

Accordingly, when I press return to the main page, a new api request occurs and I get to the top of the page. but I need me to return to the element of the list I clicked on. For example, if I clicked on the 60th element, I need to return to it. I understand that I need to interrupt the api request when I return to the main?

```
      /* States */
      const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState([]); 
      const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
      const [error, setError] = useState(false);
      const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(
        "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon"
      );
      const [nextPage, setNextPage] = useState("");
      const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(false);
      useEffect(() => {
        let cancel;
        const fetchData = () => {
          setLoading(true);
          setError(false);
          Axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: currentPage,
            cancelToken: new Axios.CancelToken((c) => (cancel = c)),
          })
          .then((res) => {
            setPokemons((prevPokemons) => {
            return [...prevPokemons, ...res.data.results];
          });
            setNextPage(res.data.next);
            setHasMore(res.data.results.length > 0);
            setLoading(false);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            if (Axios.isCancel(error)) return;
            setError(true);
          });
        };
      fetchData();
      return () => cancel();
    }, [currentPage]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities,

You make the API call in a parent component that is not unmounted (e.g. a menu, or main component

Or you keep the data in a store using something like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/). If your app is complex and needs to handle a complex state shared between components, I would go for this option.

Comment: thanks for comment! I just started learning react.js and haven’t yet studied redux) and my application is the simplest. inside the `PokemonCardContainer`, an api request occurs, a new array is formed, and a list of elements (`<PokemonCard />`) is built using `map()` on the basis of it. do i need to do api somewhere above? but i don't have the above components.

Comment: Could you do it in your router component? You can then pass the result as a parameter using the render prop

Comment: I created a new component, made an API request in it. inserted routes in it, passed parameters. `<Switch> <Route exact path="/" render={() => ( <PokemonCardContainer pokemons={pokemons} search={search} loading={loading} error={error} lastPokemonElementRef={lastPokemonElementRef} handleSearch={handleSearch} /> )} /> <Route path="/pokemon/:pokemonName" component={Pokemon} /> </Switch>`. sort of upon returning back, a new request does not occur. but the page jumps to the beginning.